# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error configuring Firefox Browser in Selenium

Tags: webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Java Version - 1.8

Eclipse Version - 2018-09 (4.9.0)

Selenium - 3.141

Firefox expandable file - v0.23.0

**My code :**

```
package testcases;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestBrowsers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\adiwakar\\Documents\\Selenium Browser files");
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

    }

}
```

**Errors:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable is a directory: C:\Users\adiwakar\Documents\Selenium Browser files
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:148)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at testcases.TestBrowsers.main(TestBrowsers.java:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you defined a path as a driver, you should define your driver executables path as a driver like following code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\adiwakar\\Documents\\yourDriver.exe");
```

Comment: Accept the answer please @AshrithaShetthalliDiwakar